# Image upload in wysiwyg custom module gives 404

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using below code in a custom module but when I want to use the Insert/Edit image --> Browse then I get a popup with a 404 of my frontend site.

```
    $configSettings = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(
        array(
        'add_widgets' => false,
        'add_variables' => false,
        'add_images' => false,
        'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/',
    )); 

    $fieldset->addField('kb_article_content', 'editor', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('support')->__('Article Content'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('support')->__('Article Content'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'kb_article_content',
        'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
        'wysiwyg'   => true,
        'config'        => $configSettings,
    ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue while working with the third-party code. I needed to add wysiwyg field and image upload didn't work.

The issue in my case happened because module admin pages used `domain.com/module_admin_route/controller/action`, while magento admin controllers use `domain.com/admin_path/module_admin_route/controller/action`. `admin_path` is just your regular path for admin panel, default is `admin`.

In normal case, image upload window is loaded via ajax request from `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController`. As you can see, this controller isn't located under Cms module, but rather under Adminhtml module. The URL for this request is then `admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index`.

For some reason magento assumes that you are on magento admin route, and uses current route to create url for ajax request, which results in `module_admin_route/cms_wysiwyg_images/index` which most likely doesn't exist in your module, hence 404.

There are probably many ways to solve it, but I found in the same module solution for the other wysiwyg field. Basically, they just find every occurrence of `module_admin_route` and replace it with default admin route:

(in your Field.php)

```
try {
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig();
        $config->setData(
            Mage::helper('module')->recursiveReplace(
                '/module_admin_route/',
                '/' . (string)Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName') . '/',
                $config->getData()
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $config = null;
    }

$fieldset->addField(
        'description',
        'editor',
        array(
             'name'  => 'description',
             'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
             'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
             'wysiwyg'   => true,
             'style'  => 'width:800px; height:500px;',
             'config' => $config,
        )
    );
```

This helper method just recursively follows config array:

```
public function recursiveReplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    if (!is_array($subject)) {
        return $subject;
    }

    foreach ($subject as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $subject[$key] = str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $subject[$key] = self::recursiveReplace($search, $replace, $value);
        }
    }
```